# Получить ID всех детей, страницы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Допустим есть страница, Games и есть дети этой страницы WarCraft, Half Life, Counter Strike. Как получить мне все id страниц детей ? Дело в том что нужно создавать множество Родителей и Детей. И что бы все время не иcкать где то id, я хочу их просто где то выводить, или получать, указывая "Родителя". Как это осуществить ?

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [get_page_children()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children)

```
<?php
// Получим страницы, по которым будет идти поиск
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

// На примере страницы с id = 2
$page_id = 2;

// Фильтруем страницы полученного ранее массива $all_wp_pages и находим в них всех потомков страницы с id = $page_id
$page_childrens = get_page_children($page_id, $all_wp_pages);

//выводим id и заголовок каждого потомка
foreach ($page_childrens as $page_children) {
    echo 'page_id: ' . $page_children->ID . '; page_title: ' . $page_children->post_title . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо на ваш код, не работает, подставлял ID страниц, родителей, дети не выводились.

Comment: это странно, потому что у меня всё отлично заработало

Comment: У меня нет, вставил в single.php где выводиться пост, и ничего. Вставлял разный айди страниц, тоже. Проверил, массив "$page_childrens" а он пустой ! возможно где то ошибка в получении детей страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Но спасибо, тем временем, я нашел ответ на другом источнике, и не много переделал сам код, скажем привел его в нормальный вид, и вывод результатов.

```
<?php
function get_all_pages($page_title) {
  $page = get_page_by_title($page_title);

  if (empty($page)) return array();

  $children = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_parent' => $page->ID,
      'fields' => 'ids',
      'posts_per_page' => -1 //Покажем всех детей ! Хороших и плохих :)
    )
  );
  array_unshift($children->posts,"{$page->ID}");
  return $children->posts;
}
//Имя страницы родителя, айди детей которых хотим получить.
$allpages = get_all_pages('Имя страницы родителя'); //Сдесь указываем имя страницы (Родителя)
foreach($allpages as $page)
{
//Выводим айди и имя страницы.
echo "<br>".$page."->".get_the_title($page);
}
?>
```

Может кому то будет полезно. Спасибо за помощь.